# Visual Studio auto-including (C#)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates, include

Is there a way to specify which namespace "includes" should be automatically added any time you create a new C# file in Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can edit the visual studio templates.

you can locate the templates for c# in:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp

Each template is in a zip file just edit the desired file in the archive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

SUggest you look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).. from JetBrains Inc ( )

it suggests, and then automatically adds namespaces for you when you add a reference to a new class that needs one, as well as many many other productivity enhancements.